# Windows 3rd party patching

Tags: powershell, windows, system-administration, patch

I'm looking for an effective way (a unicorn) to  manage patching for non WSUS deployments- I'm currently looking into patch my pc updater (free). The environment I'm working in is quite large for manual efforts- I have a threading engine running Python/powershell- so scaling it I can do. Monetarily we are not large- hehhhhh- let's try to keep this to open source/freeware. Also angentless or portability. :/ I was wondering if anyone has experience with patch my pc updater- especially with effectiveness and remote management. I've looked into the CLI switches offered and it seems doable with the portability of the app. Any red flags I should be aware of? Any other ideas that the community has used? I'm assuming I'm going to use an invoke method via powershell with wanted switches. Just wanted to ask before I spend my day wrongly tomorrow ;) thanks everyone!

Comment: WSUS has an incredible amount of holes for 3rd party patching- at least in my environment. It's great for office, and VERY standard apps, but not for one off installs like 7zip or FileZilla...AND- we do have SCCM, but the implementation has yielded patch and software inventory less than reliable. The reason I'm looking for another means is to audit the effectiveness of SCCM/WSUS, and possibly catch some floating exploits along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Understand that WSUS is the ideal solution for this - if you are forced to use something else, you will lose some functionality or reliability. SCCM may be another option, but you mentioned you have financial constraints, so that is also probably out.

As much as I love it, PowerShell might not be the ideal solution here, on it's own.

One way you might be able to work around this, if you machines are domain-joined, is to use Group Policy to "RunOnce" the patches. There was a good answer about running tasks once with Group Policy here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/442842/using-a-gpo-to-run-a-batch-file-once

Additionally, Microsoft provides some instructions on the process for offline updating here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323166

You may be able to write something in batch or PowerShell, upload the patches to a network share, then use Group Policy to make sure all machines install it.